# Injective holomorphic function problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\bar D(0,r)^c\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an injective holomorphic function from outside the disc or radius $r$. Suppose $f$ is of the form $f(z)=P(z)+g(z^{-1})$ where $P\in\mathbb{C}[Z]$ is a polynomial and $g$ is holomorphic over $D(0,\frac{1}{r})$ with $g(0)=0$. Prove that $P$ is of degree at most 1.

All your observations are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ has an isolated singularity in $\infty$. If you're not yet comfortable with that, consider the function $h(z) = f\left(\frac1z\right)$ in $D\left(0,\frac1r\right)$, which has an isolated singularity in $0$.

If $f$ (resp. $h$) is injective, what types of isolated singularities can $f$ ($h$) have at all?

Can it have

- essential singularities?
- poles (if so, of what orders)? (consider $1/f$ resp. $1/h$, which has a zero there)
- removable singularities?

The first case, by the way is ruled out here by the assumption that $P$ is a polynomial, so there's no harm in telling that an injective function can never have an essential singularity.